# Importing Pandas problems

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Although I have the latest version of Python, NumPy, Pandas, and SciPy installed, whenever I simply type `import pandas as pd`. I get the error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.testing.decorators'`

This is super strange since I used pandas earlier on in the day, and yesterday.

Can anyone explain to me what I need to do so that I can run pandas?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you weren't using your system's python when you did this.  I would suggest using the [latest version of Anaconda for this](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#download-section). 
when you restart the terminal after an install you can create an environment using

```
conda create -y -n myproject numpy pandas scipy ipython
```

You want to create a new environment for each project you build.
when you want to use this environment for your project development type this into your terminal.

```
conda activate myproject
```

now try ipython with "import pandas as pd"

Comment: While I appreciate your response, this was unhelpful. Would you happen to have any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you try it?  How did this fail?

Comment: So it didn't work initially, but after restarting my laptop, it worked perfectly fine. Thank you so much!!!